# Download data from neighbourhood with OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

I am wondering how I can download all the **streets**, and their **housenumbers** from a **neighbourhood** from *OpenStreetMap*. The neighbourhood that I am interested in is located in Rotterdam. I want to import the data into a *Neo4j* graph database.

How can I download all the streets, and their housenumber from OSM? And what is the best format to import it into Neo4j.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Don't now about NeoJ4, but you can at least have a look here for OSM data on Rotterdam : http://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Rotterdam You might as well be interested in this webpage : https://www.europeandataportal.eu/data/en/dataset/straatnamen-van-rotterdam In my point of view, you should split your question in 2 -> First : where is the data ? - Second : import GIS data in NeoJ4 ?

Comment: @underdark I found a id of the neighbourhood at OSM "way/{id}", I tried something like `wget -O file.osm "http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=` but I got `ERROR 400: Bad Request.`.

Comment: Are the house numbers actually in OpenStreetMap? Its not an authoritative database, there's always the chance that the data isn't in OSM. Can you point us to a URL of OSM showing the area you want?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

1. Use qgis but you have to do some reading
2. Use JOSM https://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Download

https://youtu.be/vl9nlBEI0as //follow this video.

Comment: I used the coords on the OSM site -after I pressed export, made a osm file and db file with QGIS. But the addr:street, housenumber city and postcode in attribute table are mostly empty. How can I get all that data from a neighbourhood?

Answer (score 0):

The best place is through overpass-api using overpass-turbo. Here is link for [roads](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/z9C) and here for [housenumbers](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/z9D). Change the map to required area and run the query and export them.  If your area is too large it may not be able to run at one time. In such case run it multiple times (if you need to run multiple times, it is recommended to use JOSM or QuickMapServices plugin in qgis)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this service (https://data.nextgis.com) to order OSM data in various GIS formats (ESRI Shape, MapInfo, Geodatabase, etc.).